# Jquery load function doesnt work effectively in IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, internet-explorer

I want to change this function in CodeIgniter become a JS. It doesn't work in IE.
Does anyone know?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (jQuery.browser.msie == true) {
        var refreshId = setInterval(auto_yesIE, 1000);
    })

    function auto_yesIE(){
        jQuery("#dummy123").load("<?php echo site_url('user/displayNumber'); ?>");
    }
```

```html
<span id="dummy123" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:17px; color:#FFCC00;"></span>
```

controller user.php

```
function displayNumber(){
    echo "123";
    //echo "456";
}
```

The function auto_yesIE is calling the controller to execute the function 'displayNumber'. the first result is "123". Eventhough I have changed it to "456" , it is still showing "123".
The cache seemed to be saved by IE . whenever I clear the cache , it showed up the new one on the next time I logged in.

Is this a JS problem? I am confused with IE.

UPDATE:

I am using Gumby Framework and this is my jQuery source.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

var oldieCheck = Boolean(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className.match(/\soldie\s/g));
if(!oldieCheck) {
document.write('<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
} else {
document.write('<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
}

if(!window.jQuery) {
if(!oldieCheck) {
  document.write('<script src="<?php echo js; ?>/libs/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"><\/script>');
  } else {
 document.write('<script src="<?php echo js; ?>/libs/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>');
  }
  }

 </script>
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using. The `jQuery.browser` object is deprecated and removed in newer versions of jQuery.

Comment: `.load()` is a simplified ajax function. To set things like cache control, use the fully configurable `.ajax()` function: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: IE is doing exactly what you've told it to do. It's not the browser's fault that you didn't tell it to not cache the result ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to prevent your request from being cached you have to use $.ajax structure or, to turn cache off for everything:

```
// at the top of your script
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```